# svn over https/ssl + nginx?

Tags: svn, nginx, https, version-control

is

- **svn** ( or any other version control system)
- over **https** (so the sending of the code is secure)
- served by nginx

possible scenario?

Or do I have to run apache?

I don't want to give ssh access to somebody else but there will be others working on the project I want to be checked in svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx doesn't support subversion as standard, you'll need to run Apache for this. You could always just proxy subversion requests to Apache and run everything else with NginX